# hexList[[1]] returns a list of decimal numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, number-representation

Sorry for not being clear about this question earlier.  I appreciate the answers I got, but the edits I made should make the question more understandable.

I have been working with hex in *Mathematica*, and for some reason I can't get a list of hex *strings* to work properly.  I have a list of hex strings - for example:

```
toCharachterHex[inChar_] := Return[IntegerString[ToCharacterCode[inChar], 16]];
```

When I call the function like this:

```
hexList = toCharachterHex["ajdv*3"]
```

*Mathematica* returns

```
{"61", "6a", "64", "76", "2a", "33"}
```

Now, when I type `hexList[[1]]`, *Mathematica* gives me

```
{"97", "106", "100", "118", "42", "51"}
```

Why would *Mathematica* do this?  Shouldn't `hexList[[1]]` give me `61`?

Comment: Something is missing here.  What exactly are *hex strings*?  Your code as shown contains no String objects at all.

Comment: Sorry.  You're right.  I fixed the question.

Comment: When *I* type `hexList[[1]]`, it properly gives me 61. So you're still missing something. Do `FullForm[hexList]` and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 5):

Well, *you* may know that they're hexadecimal numbers, but Mathematica doesn't since you didn't tell it. When you enter

```
hexList = {12, 10, 6b, 3f, 92}
```

you'll notice that the "b" and the "f" are in blue, while the numbers are black. Also notice a small space between "6" and "b", and between "3" and "f". The blue means they're undefined symbols. Mathematica sees "6b" as the expression "6 $\times$ b", no hex there.

Internally there isn't even hexadecimal, there's only numbers (binary) and symbols, and the hexadecimal only is relevant to the number's *representation*.

To enter hexadecimal numbers:

```
hexList = {16^^12, 16^^10, 16^^6b, 16^^3f, 16^^92}
```

which Mathematica accepts as

```
{18, 16, 107, 63, 146}
```

represented in the standard decimal form. If you want the output in hex:

```
BaseForm[hexList, 16]
```

will give you

> $ \{ 12_{16}, 10_{16}, 6b_{16}, 3f_{16}, 92_{16} \} $

**edit** after your update of the question
My answer still stands: Mathematica doesn't store hexadecimal numbers, only binary, because that's what the microprocessor uses as well. You tell Mathematica what the input format is, but once the numbers are stored, that will be forgotten; Mathematica doesn't store information about which input format was used. When you ask the information back, Mathematica will give it to you in the default decimal format, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I typed it into the stack exchange wrong.  I am using BaseFom to get the list.  And that is the list I am talking about in the question.

Comment: @Keegan - Then please update the question.

Comment: I just did.  I'm sorry about not being clear earlier.

Comment: @Keegan - *nema problema*. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The code in your question as presently shown does not produce the result that you describe.  All I can figure is that you are entering input like this:

```
hexList = {16^^12, 16^^10, 16^^6b, 16^^3f, 16^^92};
```

If that is the case you need to understand that these numbers are immediately and transparently converted on parsing; this is merely an input shorthand.

```
FullForm[hexList]
```

> ```
> List[18, 16, 107, 63, 146]
> ```

To put it another way:

```
HoldComplete[{16^^12, 16^^10, 16^^6b, 16^^3f, 16^^92}]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[{18, 16, 107, 63, 146}]
> ```

So not even `HoldComplete` preserves the input format.

---

### Update

Based on the comments under Steven's answer I believe you are doing this:

```
hexList = BaseForm[{97, 106, 100, 118, 42, 51}, 16];

hexList[[1]]
```

> ```
> {97, 106, 100, 118, 42, 51}
> ```

This happens because `BaseForm` is merely a formatting [wrapper](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16675/121).  Observe:

```
InputForm[hexList]
```

> ```
> BaseForm[{97, 106, 100, 118, 42, 51}, 16]
> ```

The first part of that expression is the decimal list.  If formatting alone is adequate you would get a better result by mapping the wrapper across the list:

```
hexList2 = BaseForm[#, 16] & /@ {97, 106, 100, 118, 42, 51};

hexList2[[1]]
```

> 61<sub>16</sub>

You still cannot perform numeric operations on this object:

```
hexList2[[1]] + 15
```

> 15 + 61<sub>16</sub>

Instead you could create your own head `hex` with certain properties, including formatting.  As a limited example (addition only):

```
Format[hex[n_]] := BaseForm[n, 16]
hex[n_?NumberQ] + m_?NumberQ ^:= hex[n + m]
hex[n_?NumberQ] + hex[m_?NumberQ] ^:= hex[n + m]

hexList3 = hex /@ {97, 106, 100, 118, 42, 51};

hexList3[[1]] + 15
```

> 70<sub>16</sub>

Comment: Why the `HoldComplete`?

Comment: @stevenvh It's just a way to demonstrate that even with the most powerful Hold function available the transformation takes place (because it's done during parsing).

Comment: OK, thanks. I took the liberty of adding that to your answer. (Rollback if you don't like it.)