# Error in extracting a column

Tags: manipulate, list-manipulation, data-acquisition

I imported excel data to Mathematica using this command.

```
kuruzD = Import[
"C:\\Users\\TMH\\Documents\\Problem Set 4\\kuruzData.xlsx"][[1]] //TableForm
```

I want to extract the 5th column. So, I used the command,

```
kuruzD[[All, 5]]
```

but, it results the data in 5th row? Could anyone please tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: `TableForm` is incorporated into your assignment, so `Head[kuruzD]` is `TableForm` instead of `List`. Remove `\\ TableForm`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar It works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Closed as duplicate; specifically see point #5 in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/121).  Also related: [(16664)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16664/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the link. Before, I asked the question, I searched, but I didn't find a solution.That's why I posted mine.

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for searching before posting.