# Why do two codes give different output?

Tags: syntax

I have tried the following to get the eigenvalues of several matrices of the type:

```
J := D[{i - l*r - ux*r*x - uy*r*y, -mx*x + ex*ux*r*x, -my*y + 
  ey*uy*r*y}, {{r, x, y}}] // StandardForm
```

Then with three possible solutions given by `Solve`

```
FullSimplify[J/. Solve[i - l*r - ux*r*x - uy*r*y == 0 && -mx*x + ex*ux*r*x == 
 0 && -my*y + ey*uy*r*y == 0, {r, x, y}]]
Eigenvalues[%[[1]]]
```

But it does not give me the eigenvalues, it just outputs:

> Eigenvalues[{{-l, -((i ux)/l), -((i uy)/l)}, {0, -mx + (ex i ux)/l, 0}, {0, 0, -my + (ey i uy)/l}}]

Only the following code gives them:

```
FullSimplify[J/. Solve[i - l*r - ux*r*x - uy*r*y == 0 && -mx*x + ex*ux*r*x == 
 0 && -my*y + ey*uy*r*y == 0, {r, x, y}]]
%[[1]]
Eigenvalues[%]
```

Why? In other words, why is

```
Function[%[[1]]]
```

different from

```
%[[1]]
Function[%]
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StandardForm` is a wrapper.

```
j = D[{i - l*r - ux*r*x - uy*r*y, -mx*x + ex*ux*r*x, -my*y + ey*uy*r*y}, {{r, x, y}}];

FullSimplify[j /. Solve[
    i - l*r - ux*r*x - uy*r*y == 0 && -mx*x + ex*ux*r*x == 
      0 && -my*y + ey*uy*r*y == 0, {r, x, y}]];

Eigenvalues[%[[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. no need to use `j:=` just use `j=` and try not to use UPPERCASE for first letters.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that SandardForm could have effects on the following calculations :/

Comment: @Ouistiti Yes; please read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16664/121) for another example.