# Prevent graphics from rendering inside a held expression

Tags: graphics, front-end, evaluation, output-formatting, hold

Assuming each odd line is input I would like the even lines to be the output of the following lines.

[image]

In the above the `Graphics` are inside `Hold`/`HoldForm` therefore IMO it doesn't make sense to have Mathematica try and render such expressions.  For example `Hold[Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]]` throws an error because built in colors don't get replaced.

How might I prevent `Graphics` from being rendered and instead print the Graphics code?

The following code works at reassigning Graphics inside Hold/HoldForm, but it prints something like `Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}]` without the `HoldForm`/`Hold`.

```
Unprotect[Graphics]
Graphics /: HoldForm[Graphics[x___]] := (
   InputForm[Graphics[x]]
   );
Graphics /: Hold[Graphics[x___]] := (
   InputForm[Graphics[x]]
   );
```

Ideally the code should be generalized to work with irregular constructs like `HoldForm["a",Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}]]`.  More importantly, how might you insure `HoldComplete` doesn't render Graphics either.  As [rm-rf](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30739/rm-rf) pointed out the [Villegas–Gayley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) trick will likely be needed.

---

Simplifying John Fultz's answer slightly, you get the following:

```
Map[
 (
   Unprotect[#];
   # /: MakeBoxes[#[expr_], fmt : StandardForm | TraditionalForm] := 
    Block[{Graphics, Graphics3D},
     RowBox[{ToString[#], "[", MakeBoxes[expr, fmt], "]"}]
     ];
   Protect[#]
   ) &, {Hold, HoldForm, HoldComplete}
 ]
```

Comment: This is not exactly what you want but: `ToString[#, InputForm] &@Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]`

Comment: Also not exactly what you want, use `graphics` instead of `Graphics` and replace when it's time to render.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get anywhere by monkeying with `Graphics`. As I see it, solving your problem requires changing the way the fonte end's output printer works. I don't have a clue on to do that.

Comment: @m_goldberg you are right.  At this point I am just trying to prevent the rendering of Graphics, which I have already partly done with `MakeBoxes`.  Other ideas are certainly welcome.

Comment: Possibly related: [Making customized InputForm and ShortInputForm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6224185/590388).

Comment: Also closely related: ["Conversion of expressions by the FrontEnd."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5814442/590388)

Comment: Related: [(16664)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16664/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

John Fultz alluded to using the [Villegas-Gayley pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656).  Since I believe that is the correct approach to this problem here is an implementation.

```
mk : MakeBoxes[(Hold | HoldForm | HoldComplete | HoldPattern)[__], _] :=
  Block[{$hldGfx = True, Graphics, Graphics3D}, mk] /; ! TrueQ[$hldGfx]
```

I included [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldPattern.html) to complete the Hold functions.  This now works at any depth:

```
Hold[1, 2, foo[3, Graphics[{Green, Circle[]}], 4], 5]
```

> ```
> Hold[1, 2, foo[3, Graphics[{Green, Circle[]}], 4], 5]
> ```

---

#### Overhead

[Jacob Akkerboom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4330/jacob-akkerboom) questioned the overhead of this general rule attached to `MakeBoxes`.  To test this I converted a large expression to Box form using `ToBoxes` (which calls `MakeBoxes`), and timed the operation with and without this definition as well as several alternatives.  Here are the results (in version 7).  Each test was performed in a fresh kernel, using this code:

```
expr = Expand[(1 + x + y)^4 (2 - z)^5 (q - 7 - a)^7 (b + r - 4)^6];
ToBoxes[expr] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

- Raw (no additional `MakeBoxes` rules):  0.7940454
- `Alternatives` DownValue on `MakeBoxes`: 1.1030631
- Four individual DownValues on `MakeBoxes`: 1.4690841
- Four UpValues on Hold* functions: 0.7890451

(Incidentally, use of the Notations Package causes far larger overhead; the timing performed in my standard configuration was 3.5652039 seconds.)

It appears that Jacob's concern is valid as the overhead of my method above is significant, though not extreme.  I usually attach rules to `MakeBoxes` to avoid having to `Unprotect` system Symbols but I may have to reconsider that practice.  If you prefer unprotecting system Symbols to the overhead you may use this:

```
(
  Unprotect @ #;
  mk : MakeBoxes[Blank[#], _] /; ! TrueQ[$hldGfx] ^:= 
    Block[{$hldGfx = True, Graphics, Graphics3D}, mk];
  Protect @ #
) & ~Scan~ {Hold, HoldForm, HoldComplete, HoldPattern}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now there are 2 good answers.  I don't love the idea of changing the right answer after so long, but this is definitely the right/better/more complete answer.

Comment: @Liam You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.

Comment: @Liam I simplified my code; please take a look and let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I suppose that this definition will slow down `MakeBoxes` quite a bit. When you call `MakeBoxes[whatever[b]]`, I imagine it will at least have to test something like `Hold === whatever`, `HoldForm === whatever` etc. I think the definition will be associated with `MakeBoxes`. Also I suspect `MakeBoxes` is used once whenever you type a character in the front end. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @Jacob please see update

Comment: @Mr.Wizard very interesting, thank you kindly! :)

Comment: You forgot some alternatives :P Hehe. Btw, I also like this approach more, +1

Comment: @Rojo which one did you want me to include?  John's answer also uses UpValues so I assumed it would perform the same as my second method.  Did I miss something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, chat?

Comment: @Rojo Sorry, no time now.  Later I hope! :-)

Answer (score 18):

Recall that the rendering of `Graphics` has nothing to do with evaluation.  It is done entirely in typesetting.  And therefore, a robust solution will treat this as a problem of typesetting, and not as a problem of evaluation.

Once you frame the problem properly, the solution is fairly straightforward.  What you want to do is to change the typesetting of `Hold` (and friends).  Take a look at this:

```
Unprotect[Hold];
Hold /: MakeBoxes[Hold[expr_], fmt : StandardForm | TraditionalForm] :=
  Block[{Graphics, Graphics3D}, Unprotect[Graphics, Graphics3D]; 
  Clear[Graphics, Graphics3D]; 
  RowBox[{"Hold", "[", MakeBoxes[expr, fmt], "]"}]]
Protect[Hold]
```

Fortunately, `Hold` (and `HoldForm` and `HoldComplete`) has no typesetting rules directly attached to it that you're fighting, which you can determine using `FormatValues[Hold]`.  But `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` do; it's how typesetting of graphics works at all.  We want to suppress those rules, but only within the typesetting of `Hold`.  So we use `Block` to contain the damage we're about to do to the `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` symbols, and then use `Clear` to clear them.  From there on out, we let `MakeBoxes` do what it would normally do.

Note that this example cheats a bit; it only works if you pass one argument to `Hold`.  I did that for purpose of code simplicity and illustration.  To make the formatting rules work properly for `Hold[expr___]`, I would have to write multiple and more sophisticated rules, or I would have to use the [Villegas-Gayley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) trick.

---

Edit: As came up in the comment discussion, it really isn't necessary to `Unprotect` and `Clear` the symbols `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`, as `Block` is effectively doing that already.  I've considered editing the code to make it shorter/simpler, but perhaps the existing code is clearer for people who don't fully understand how `Block` works (and, public confession here, while I understand `Block` scoping, I had just plumb forgotten how `Block` initializes variables, so this more an oversight on my part than a planned teaching moment).

Comment: Nice explanation and solution,+1. It is not clear to me however, why `Unprotect` and `Clear` are needed, since `Block` automatically clears all symbol's definitions and attributes (in contrast to ``Internal`InheritedBlock``).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I think it was simply John Fultz kind attempt to make it clearer to what is exactly going on.  They way it is currently written makes perfect sense(at least to me).  Additionally if I don't understand the differences between `With`,`Module`, and `Block`/`Internal\`InheritedBlock`.  How do you prevent evaluation of a function? Well by Removing and Clearing it of course.

Comment: Actually, believe it or not, there are limits to my knowledge of Mathematica, and for some reason, it didn't occur to me to see if `Block` would automatically clear a Protected System symbol.  I appreciate @Liam reading the benefit of hidden wisdom into my answer, though! :)  And, in fact, that response gives me pause about editing the answer to shorten the code.

Comment: Also `Clear` probably only clears `OwnValues` and `DownValues` etc. The following code shows you cannot use Clear to get rid of the behavior of `Graph`, but you can use `Block`. `ue = UndirectedEdge; gr:= Graph[{ue[1,2],ue[2,3]}]; AtomQ/@{gr, Unprotect@Graph; Clear@Graph; gr, Unevaluated@@Block[{Graph},Hold@Evaluate@ gr ] }` evaluates to `{True, True, False}`

Comment: ...where one should realize that `AtomQ[Unevaluated[1]]` gives `True`.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Note that if one changes `gr := Graph[{ue[1, 2], ue[2, 3]}];` into `gr = Graph[{ue[1, 2], ue[2, 3]}];` (that is `SetDelayed` to `Set`) in your code it gives `{True,True,True}` instead of `{True, True, False}`. What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom `AtomQ` has no any `Hold*` attribute, so `AtomQ[Unevaluated[1]]` is identical to `AtomQ[1]`. Note that `AtomQ[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` returns `False`.

Comment: In reply to your last comment: Yes, you are correct. I was hoping to clear any confusion when I was comparing `AtomQ[Graph[...]]` with `AtomQ[Unevaluated[Graph[...]]]`, where the former gives `True` and the latter gives `False`. `Unevaluated` is not responsible for the difference :)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov in reply to your first comment: ah yes this is precisely the point :). If you "`Set`" `gr = Graph[...]`, then the expression with head `Graph` is evaluated outside the `Block`. Note that blocking `Graph` later will have no effect as the expression with head `Graph` is already converted into an atomic expression. Even if it's `Head` is still `Graph`, it is not a "proper head". Anyway the function `Graph` generates this atomic expression. If you evaluate `gr` inside the `Block`, then the expression with head `Graph` is not converted into an atom, as `Graph` has no special meaning.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks for the explanations, it is clear now. And I think it is worth to post in a separate answer your (very significant!) points.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but an extended comment.

Regarding your assertion

> This occurs because although the front end attempts to render the Graphics element the internal code won't replace Directives inside of a Held expression.

This is not the case. Consider

```
Hold[Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thick, Circle[]}]]
```

[image: thickred.png]

and

```
 With[{red = Red}, Hold[Graphics[{red, Circle[]}]]]
```

[image: withred.png]

So the error message comes from using the built-in symbol `Red` and not from the front end doing anything funny with directives.

Comment: Is Color Directives more appropriate then?  Seems to be an issue for all colors.

Comment: @Liam. `RGBColor[1, 0, 0]` is a color directive; `Red`,`Green`, `Blue`, etc. are not.

Comment: That's fair although I find it odd that the colors are listed under `guide/GraphicsDirectives` Graphics Directives in the docs.  Would simply colors be an appropriate name?

Comment: @Liam. I regard that to be an error in the docs. They are symbols that **evaluate** to graphic directives, but of course not inside `Hold`.

Comment: @Liam. You might well ask "Why then does `Thick` work?" I wonder about that myself.

Comment: @m_goldberg I should think the answer is obvious. `Thick` is a graphics directive.  The documentation for `Thick` directly makes this statement.  As for `Red`, `Green`, etc., you're absolutely correct in saying they aren't graphics directives.  But they do evaluate directly into a graphics directives.  For that reason, I don't think the choice to put them in the `guide/GraphicsDirectives` guide page is inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

In M11+, if you are willing to create a new Hold* wrapper, you could define:

```
SetAttributes[HoldFormatting,HoldAll];

MakeBoxes[HoldFormatting[expr_], StandardForm]^:=MakeBoxes[DisableFormatting[expr]]
```

Then:

```
HoldFormatting[{1+1, Graphics[{Green,Circle[]}]}]
```

> {1 + 1, Graphics[{Green, Circle[]}]}

Answer (score 2):

If you take @JohnFultz 's initial comment

> Recall that the rendering of Graphics has nothing to do with
>   evaluation. It is done entirely in typesetting. And therefore, a
>   robust solution will treat this as a problem of typesetting, and not
>   as a problem of evaluation.

then I would ask, why are you using `Hold` in the first place? `Hold` is for the *kernel*, not for the front-end. I tried your `Hold[Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]]` and saw the error too; but look at the expression inside the notebook (Cmd-Shift-E on Mac)

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"Hold", "[", 
  GraphicsBox[{Red, CircleBox[{0, 0}]}], "]"}]], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.597606336110736*^9}]
```

The front-end wraps all in a `Cell` (content in a notebook lives inside cells). `Cell` contains boxes, and boxes are generated from the expression. It also replaced `Graphics` by `GraphicsBox` and `Circle` by `CircleBox`. `Red` is unknown to the front-end as it is.

Try

```
Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}] // InputForm
```

and you *see*

```
Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Circle[{0, 0}]}]
```

Funny enough, it seems the *kernel* knows about `Red` and `Circle`'s default and the front-end gets those symbols evaluated. `Graphics` gets passed as is, although -I bet- it must have some rules in the *kernel* that allow the front-end to get a clearer command.

If you do

```
Hold[Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]] // InputForm
```

you see in the front-end

```
Hold[Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]]
```

The *kernel* didn't attempt to resolve the expression at all - as expected.

I am far from being an expert on these things, but I think the central issue is trying to use `Hold` in the front-end, which as we can see, has no effect. The front-end has its own transformation rules, from the expressions it gets from the *kernel* to the cell and box objects it needs to display.

The good -and confusing- thing is that the *kernel* can manipulate those symbols too (`Cell`, boxes, `InputForm`, etc), so one can return **formatted** expressions to the front-end and this is how (IMHO) the problem should be approached.

So a very simple approach is just to use `InputForm` as suggested above.