# Why is DownValues releasing RuleDelayed's hold for Graphics?

Tags: evaluation, downvalues

I am trying to understand `DownValues` in regards to the evaluation of its output. Consider this:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] := 1 + 1;

In[2]:= DownValues[f]
Out[2]= {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> 1 + 1}
```

So far so good. Now lets change f so that it includes a graphic:

```
In[3]:= f[x_] := Graphics[Circle[]]
In[3]:= DownValues[f]
```

[image]

It works, but why the 1 + 1 remains unevaluated while the Graphics command is evaluated? This becomes a problem in a case like this:

```
In[4]:= f[r_] := Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, r]]
In[4]:= DownValues[f]
```

[image]
[image]

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to prevent the evaluation of the definitions returned by DownValues?

I am using Mathematica 10.1 / Win7

**Motivation**: I was exploring the idea of creating a code analysis function to help me create function calls graphs. For this, I need to be able to fetch the unevaluated definitions of all the functions defined in the Global` context.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Let me see if I can find it.  Short answer: it's just an output formatting result, not standard evaluation.

Comment: Found it; proposed duplicate: [(32296)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32296/121); see also: [(5617685)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5617685/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards the solution.