# What are the differences between using MakeBoxes and Interpretation?

Tags: evaluation, boxes, custom-notation

Say I want to define a custom graphical representation for my function `foo`.
I can do this using `MakeBoxes` as in the following:

```
foo /: MakeBoxes[foo[x_, y_], StandardForm] := ToBoxes @ Graphics[{
    Point@{x, y}
  }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
]
```

so that evaluating `foo[1, 1.5]` produces a `Graphics` object accordingly.
This also works consistently if another function `foobar` is defined to act on a `foo` object, like in

```
foobar[foo[x_, y_]] := (Print["Matched"]; x + y)
```

There is another way to achieve the same result, which is using `Interpretation`.
I could define `foo2` as

```
foo2[x_, y_] := Interpretation[
    Graphics[{
        Point@{x, y}
      }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
    ],
    foo2[x, y]
]
```

This produces the same result, and works consistently when defining another function like

```
foobar2[foo2[x_, y_]] := (Print["Matched"]; x + y)
```

I (vaguely) know that `Interpretation` produces an `InterpretationBox`, so I'm guessing there should be fundamental differences between this and the result of using `MakeBoxes`, but I don't know what they are exactly.
What are the circumstances in which one function should be preferred with respect to the other? And what the intrinsic differences?

Comment: I completely rewrote the answer in the hope that it will be clearer and more educational.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Point of conversion

A large and perhaps key difference is that `MakeBoxes` (`foo`) only transforms the expression into the expanded form when it is converted to Box form.  It's [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) remains unchanged.

```
foo[1, 0.3] // InputForm
```

> ```
> foo[1, 0.3`]
> ```

This means that you can operate upon the expression in every standard way without thought to a hidden internal format.

```
Sin /@ foo[1, 0.3`];
%[[2]]
```

> ```
> 0.29552
> ```

`Interpretation` (`foo2`) does not allow this:

```
Sin /@ foo2[1, 0.3`];
%[[2]]
```

[image]

The cause:

```
Sin /@ foo2[1, 0.3`] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Interpretation[
>  Sin[Graphics[{Point[{1, 0.3}]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]], 
>  Sin[foo2[1, 0.3]]]
> ```

#### Held expressions

Another difference manifests when these expressions are wrapped in Hold constructs.  Because `MakeBoxes` works outside the standard evaluation sequence the graphic still displays.  `foo2` however must evaluate before `Interpretation` is even part of the expression.

```
HoldForm[ foo[1, 0.3] ]

HoldForm[ foo2[1, 0.3] ]
```

[image]

Related to this point: [Prevent graphics render inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32296/121)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that you want to create a special display form for `foo` that can be used in all contexts, you should use *neither* of these solutions.  Why?

- `MakeBoxes` controls how `foo` will be formatted.  This is part of what you want.  But the way you used it, the formatting is *one-way*.  It will not be possible to convert the *already formatted* output as a `foo` expression. For example, if you edit the output cell directly, or by copying the output and paste it elsewhere, it will behave as `Graphics` and not as `foo`.
- `Interpretation` is meant for typesetting only, and cannot be used in normal calculations.  `Interpreation["two", 2]` will format in a special way so that if you copy the formatted output, and paste it elsewhere, it will *look* like `"two"`, but it will *behave* like `2`.  However, if you do not format it inside of a notebook and then copy it, it will not be possible to use it as a substitute for `2`.  For example, `Head@Interpretation["two", 2]` will return `Interpretation` and not `Integer`.  Thus, before `Interpretation` will start behaving equivalently to its second argument in computations, *you must display it, then copy the displayed form*.

#### What should you use then?

I suggest you use a specific combination of `MakeBoxes` and `Interpretation` that I presented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99920/12).  This will work both ways:

- It formats the expression in a graphical way
- The formatted expression can be turned back into a computable expression (with head `foo`)

Example:

```
MakeBoxes[expr : foo3[x_, y_], StandardForm | TraditionalForm] := 
 ToBoxes@Interpretation[
   Graphics[{Point@{x, y}}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], 
   expr
 ]
```

Under the hood, this creates an `InterpretationBox`. `InterpretationBox` is a special box form that already contains the expression it represents.  Thus you do not need to create an explicit back-conversion rule using `MakeExpression`.

The above could also be written as

```
MakeBoxes[expr : foo3[x_, y_], StandardForm | TraditionalForm] := 
  With[{boxes = ToBoxes@Graphics[{Point@{x, y}}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]}, 
    InterpretationBox[boxes, expr]
  ]
```

This form will sometimes give more flexibility.

---

With `foo3` you can do the following:

[image]

Neither of the two approaches you describe  (`foo` and `foo2`) will behave this way.

Comment: Related: [(4112299)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112299/618728)

Comment: I tend to vote for your answers a lot but in this case I hesitate to.  This doesn't appear to me to be an answer to this question.  Can you convince me otherwise?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Maybe tomorrow, I should be doing something else right now ... will log off.  Perhaps OP can comment is this is useful at all and I will edit or delete the answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see your point, but perhaps the question poses a false dichotomy.  The question asks whether to use `MakeBoxes` _or_ `Interpretation`.  But the two are normally used _together_, as illustrated by this response. I suggest that `Interpretation` does not have much use outside of typesetting because the wrapper just "gets in the way".  (Incidentally, I tend to use higher level UI constructs like `Interpretation` over lower level box constructs like `InterpretationBox`, but that is just a matter of taste.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm not sure I understand your second point. If I do `var = foo[1, 1.5]; Head @ var` I get `foo`

Comment: I find this answer very interesting, even if maybe it approaches the question less directly that Mr.Wizard's one. It shows a better way to use `MakeBoxes` and `Interpretation` together

Comment: @glS He means if you copy the *output* and try to use it as input.  That is what this answer is about.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard but the way I understood it, that's the third point. The second point states that evaluating `Head` on the output of `foo[1, 1.5]` does not give `foo`, but this is not the case, is it?

Comment: @glS (and Mr.W) Sorry for the late response. My point was that although your use case was not fully clear to me, it was my impression that you should use *neither* of those two approaches.  As WReach said, `Interpretation` (`foo2`) is for *typesetting*. You would use it only if you plan to copy the result manually (copy and paste) and re-use it.  Your `MakeBoxes` solution is fine for as long as you do programmatic manipulations only (e.g. `var = foo[...]`), but it won't allow you to copy and re-use the output.  Or to edit the output cell and do something with the output.

Comment: @glS My solution will let you use the result in either of those ways: you can assign it to a variable programmatically and use it, or use it as a sub-part of a larger expression.  But you can also start typing in the output cell and re-use the result there.  Or copy and paste the output into another expression and re-use it.  You can do this with `foo3` but you cannot do this with `foo`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I rewrote the answer, hope it's clearer.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, I see your point more clearly now (even though I didn't question the usefulness of the answer also for the previous version!). So am I understanding correctly that the only reason `Interpretation` does not work like your version is that it must be printed on a notebook for it to be converted into an `InterpretationBox`, which instead works as we want?

Comment: @glS Yes, you could put it that way.  To be honest, I never really understood what `Interpretation` was good for in practice, when used on its own (without MakeBoxes).  But I am sure that there are some good uses that I have not thought of.

Comment: You've got my vote now. :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs, If `foo` with its parameters is a `Function`, eg, `foo[x_, y_] := (x + y + #) &`, then it seems to ignore the `MakeBoxes` upvalue. Can you reproduce this and if so is there a workaround?

Comment: @Szabolcs, to clarify, I substituted `SuscriptBox` for `Graphics`, eg `foo /: MakeBoxes[c : foo[x_, y_], 
  form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := 
 With[{boxes = SubscriptBox[x, y]}, InterpretationBox[boxes, c]]`

Comment: @alancalvitti It would immediately evaluate to a `Function[...]`, which does not have formatting rules. To keep the formatting, use sub-values, i.e. define `foo[x_, y_][args_] := ...`. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Szabolcs, understood. However, `foo[x_, y_][args_]` seems to work when `x` ,`y` are numbers,  but for example `foo[a,b]` where `a` and `b` are undefined symbols evaluates to expressions involving `$CellContext`, or gives an error with expressions like `foo[{1,2},3]`: `An unknown box name List was sent as the BoxForm for an expression...`