# InterpretationBox problem with symbolic expressions

Tags: evaluation, custom-notation, boxes

Related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138143/what-are-the-differences-between-using-makeboxes-and-interpretation/138149?noredirect=1#comment526542_138149) question,

Why does this `InterpretationBox` construct work when `x`, `y` are numbers but not undefined symbols or more complex expressions?

```
foo /: MakeBoxes[c : foo[x_, y_], form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := With[{boxes = SubscriptBox[x, y]}, InterpretationBox[boxes, c]]
```

**EDIT**

Originally intended to state the full problem but then simplified it. kglr's answer does not work as intended, so here is the complication:

Would like `foo[r,m]` to display in subscript form, but when provided with a `SubValue`, it should evaluate to the rhs:

```
foo[r_,m_][h_]:= m h + r
```

**END EDIT**

Works:

```
foo[2,3]
```

> Subscript[2, 3]

Plugging in `x` inserts `$CellContext`:

```
foo[2, x]

Subscript[2, $CellContext`x]
```

or fails with `List`:

```
foo[{1, 2}, 3]
```

> An unknown box name (List) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression.
>   Check the format rules for the expression.

Comment: I recommend a [talk on typesetting by Jason Harris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy6-RU6ZAX4), that is definitely broader but it won't be a waste of time. Your problem is addressed somewhere for sure.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Adding a format for `foo` should have no effect on the evaluation of `foo`. You probably have a lingering definition of `foo` that is causing issues.

Comment: @CarlWoll, just tried on a fresh kernel with same results. Using `foo[r_,m_][h_]:= m h + r` and kglr's `MakeBoxes` def, `foo[2,3][4]` displays the subscript form but does not evaluate `foo` to rhs.

Comment: Did you include @kglr's `ClearAll[foo]` command as well?

Answer (score 3):

Answering the title question, when creating boxes, everything should be a `*Box` object or a string (or possibly a list). Inside of a box object, excluding options, again, everything should be a `*Box` object or a string (or list). There is one exception to this rule. It is ok to use integers instead of the corresponding strings. I'm not sure why this exception is made, as it results in the confusion that you face when using `x` instead of `1` breaks things.

As for the actual format code, another possibility is:

```
foo /: MakeBoxes[foo[x_, y_], form_] := MakeBoxes[Subscript[x, y], form]
```

Finally, I think your edited issue is that you included `ClearAll[foo]` after defining the subvalue definition.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `boxes = SubscriptBox[x, y]` with `SubscriptBox[ToBoxes@x, ToBoxes@y]`:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo /: MakeBoxes[c : foo[x_, y_], form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := 
 With[{boxes = SubscriptBox[ToBoxes @ x, ToBoxes @ y]}, InterpretationBox[boxes, c]]
```

***Examples:***

```
foo[2, 3]
```

> Subscript[2, 3]

```
foo[2, 3]
```

> Subscript[2, x]

```
foo[{a, b}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> Subscript[{a,b}, {1,2,3}]

As suggested by @Kuba in comments, use

```
boxes = SubscriptBox[MakeBoxes @ x, MakeBoxes @ y]
```

to avoid evaluation leaks in cases like `Hold @ foo[f[1 + 2], x + y]`.

Comment: `MakeBoxes` should be used to avoid evaluation leaks when things like `Hold @ foo[1+1, 2]` are being (?)typeset.

Comment: Thank you @Kuba; excellent point. I will update with your suggestion if you do not intend to post it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, a separate answer is not needed.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, however, this doesn't work with my intended application, which is to have `SubValues` for `foo`. I originally intended to add this bit but in the end decided to simplify it. Will edit Q.

Comment: @Kuba, please see edit - do I need to ask as a separate Q?

Comment: @alancalvitti afaict Carl's answer is what I consider the answer. Or did I miss the point?

Comment: @kglr, @Kuba, `boxes = SubscriptBox[MakeBoxes @ x, MakeBoxes @ y]` doesn't work. It doesn't evaluate the `SubValue`