# Is it safe to Unprotect everything? What are the implications?

Tags: built-in-symbols, attributes, format

What is the reason for built-in symbols to be `Protected`?

What happens if I `Unprotect` built-ins and add my own `SetDelayed`, etc.? Is it degraded performance?

What are general precautions in doing that?

---

My particular scenario is that I want to add custom formatting to `Hold[]` expressions and I can not assign because tag `Hold` is protected. Will this affect performance if I unprotect and do it anyways?

Comment: You can also assign values to `Format` if you are just interested in appearance.

Comment: No, it is not safe to Unprotect everything. The implication is more bugs in your code and wasting your time finding them.

Comment: You should edit this question to focus it on real problem: changing the appearance of held expressions.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I understand this is unproductive but unprotecting all built-ins AND modifying `Hold`? lol, that sounds like the stuff nightmares are made of, if you are not sure what you're doing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is to prevent users to mess with it. Unprotecting *something* is not necessarily dangerous, but unprotecting *everything* definitely is. Performance is probably not the issue. The real danger is that you replace a very important feature of a built-in symbol by chance. Since built-in symbols often have the `ReadProtected` attribute, you cannot check beforehand whether you are going to overwrite anything important.

Regarding the appearance of held expressions: One can do this

```
Unprotect[Hold];
Format[Hold[a___]] := Held[a];
Protect[Hold];
```

at the cost of the puzzling results

```
a = Hold[1 + 1]
a // FullForm

(* Held[2] *)
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)
```

Internally, the expression should be treated by Mathematica as usual; only the appearance was changed in a counterintuitive way. This particular issue can be fixed by giving the `HoldAll` attribute to `Held`:

```
SetAttributes[Held,HoldAll]
a
(* Held[1+1] *)
```

But still, messing with internals is a very, very bad idea.

Addendum: Mathematica also provides the attribute `Locked` which prevents changing the `Attibutes` of a symbol. If that symbol has also the attribute `Protected` then it cannot be messed with any more. That seems to be the way how developers are meant to protect their users from themselves. However, one cannot rely on the combination `Protected` and `Locked` being used consistently for *all* "important" symbols.

Comment: very nice answer + 1 !

Answer (score 15):

There is a typesetting step after formatting, and `MakeBoxes` definitions do not require unprotecting `Hold`, you will just add more `DonwValues` for `MakeBoxes`.

```
MakeBoxes[Hold[a___], fmt_] := With[
    {foo = MakeBoxes[Panel[Column[{a}]], fmt]}
  , InterpretationBox[
        RowBox[{"Hold", "[", foo, "]"}]
      , Hold[a]
    ]
]

Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 4 + 4]
```

[image]

It is always crucial to not let any evaluation leak during typesetting. Here, the content from `Hold` is passed directly to another `MakeBoxes` which holds its arguments.

Comment: It is worth noting that this method does come at the cost of some overhead compared to unprotecting `Hold` and attaching the formatting to it using `TagSet`; see: [(39675)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39675/121).  However in most cases it should not matter and of course +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard somehow I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The danger when you unprotect things is that there may be unintended side effects. For example, say we unprotect "Plus"...

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Plus = Times;
```

Now if I ask for

```
5+4
20

Integrate[x^2 + 3, x]
x^3
```

(which is not right at all).

It is very difficult to anticipate all the consequences of unprotecting the meaning of basic symbols.