# Make a custom object look like MatrixForm of a matrix?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, boxes

Let's say I have a custom object that I denote

```
Obj[a,b,c,...]
```

There are always `n^2` entries in the object for some integer `n`, and I'd like it to appear as a matrix once it is entered. For example, I'd like to get the following output:

```
Obj[x11,x12,x21,x22]
```

> [image]

and

```
Obj[x11,x12,x13,x21,x22,x23,x31,x32,x33]
```

> [image]

And of course it should also just give the other way around:

[image]

> `Obj[x11,x12,x21,x22]`

I guess the biggest challenge is to make it work for any `n` automatically. Is it possible to do that in Mathematica?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InterpretationBox` will take care of making safe round trip from boxes to expression but we need to take extra care during condition checking and partition not to evaluate `Obj's` arguments.

It does not matter that `Obj` is not holding them, `Obj` itself can be held. `Hold @ Obj[1,2,3,4]` etc.

#### Edit to the old code

As xzczd has noticed, an Input cell with e.g. `Obj[1,2,3,4]` shows explicit `MatrixForm` after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shit</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Which is strange, the more that I can't reproduce that with combinations of `NotebookRead`/`MakeExpression`/`MakeBoxes` etc.

The problem seems to be caused by `TagBox` so we can take even more extra care and work around it:

```
Obj /: MakeBoxes[ 
  o : Obj[args__], StandardForm
] /; IntegerQ @ Sqrt @ Length @ Unevaluated @ args := With[
  { array = (
      List @@@ Partition[Hold[args], Sqrt@Length[Unevaluated[args]]]
    ) /. Hold[lists__] :> Map[
      Function[x, MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm], HoldFirst]
    , Unevaluated @ {lists}
    , {2}
    ]
  }
, InterpretationBox[
    RowBox[{ "(", "\[NoBreak]"
    , GridBox[array, RowSpacings -> 1, ColumnSpacings -> 1
      , RowAlignments -> Baseline, ColumnAlignments -> Center
      ]
    , "\[NoBreak]", ")"
    }]
  , o
  ]
]
```

#### Old

```
Obj /: MakeBoxes[
  o : Obj[args__], StandardForm
] /; IntegerQ @ Sqrt @ Length[Unevaluated[args]] := With[
  { matrixFormBoxes = (
      List @@@ Partition[Hold[args], Sqrt @ Length[Unevaluated[args]]]
    ) /. Hold[lists__] :> MakeBoxes[MatrixForm[{lists}]]
  }
, InterpretationBox[
    matrixFormBoxes
  , o
  ]
]
```

```
Obj[1, 2, 3, 4]
Obj[1, 2, 4]
Hold @ Obj[Echo[1], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

[image]

```
% // ReleaseHold
```

[image]

```
% // FullForm
```

> ```
> Obj[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
> ```

related:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149668/5478

Comment: One issue remained: if one writes e.g. `Obj[1, 2, 3, 4]` in an input cell, and press `Ctrl+Shift+N`, then the code will display as `MatrixForm[{{x11, x12, x13}, {x21, x22, x23}, {x31, x32, x33}}]`.

Comment: Good workaround. I just found another possible workaround, not as flexible as yours, but simpler: modify `MakeBoxes[MatrixForm[{lists}]]` to `MakeBoxes[{lists}, TraditionalForm]`.

Comment: As to evaluation leaks, box formatting functions should, in my opinion, always use "strong" `HoldAllComplete`-type holding, to avoid nasty things like: `Hold[___, nasty, ___] ^:= Print@"Leak!"; HoldComplete@Obj[1, 2, nasty, 3]`.

Comment: @jkuczm You are right, I don't know why I'm always hesitant to use HoldAllComplete. p.s. any idea about mentioned issue?

Comment: @Kuba Just use `HoldComplete` instead of `Hold` and `HoldAllComplete` instead of `HoldFirst`. Or did you mean the issue mentioned by xzczd? Then I don't have anything better than what is already in your answer.

Comment: @jkuczm yep, I meant the latter. The problem is I don't know why it happens and if it should happen. Thanks for tips anyway.

Comment: @Kuba `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`N` calls ``BoxForm`ConvertForm[BoxData[RowBox[{"Obj", "[", RowBox[{"1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4"}], "]"}]], StandardForm, StandardForm, "Input"]``. It seems that `MakeBoxes` called by ``BoxForm`ConvertForm`` somehow ignores standard formatting of builtin `...Form` wrappers and converts `MatrixForm[...]` to `RowBox[{"MatrixForm", "[", ..., "]"}]` instead of ordinary `GridBox`. I don't know how it happens.

Comment: @jkuczm I guess it is worth reporting. Thanks for investigation.

Answer (score 6):

[`InterpretationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationBox.html) used in [answer by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159338/14303) and [by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159340/14303) allows you to copy formatted object and keep its proper interpretation as an `Obj` expression, but you can't edit such formatted objects. You could make `InterpretationBox` editable by using [`Editable -> True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Editable.html) option but this will allow you to just edit formatted version while interpretation would incorrectly remain unchanged.

To make copied formatted object editable, instead of `InterpretationBox`, you could use [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox.html) with appropriate `DisplayFunction`:

```
Obj // ClearAll
Obj /: MakeBoxes[Obj@args__, StandardForm] := Module[{n, k}, 
    n = Length@Unevaluated@args;
    k = Sqrt@n;
    TemplateBox[
        MakeBoxes /@ Unevaluated@{args},
        "Obj",
        Tooltip -> "Obj",
        DisplayFunction -> (Evaluate@RowBox@{"(", "\[NoBreak]", GridBox[
            Partition[Array[Slot, n], k],
            RowSpacings -> 1, ColumnSpacings -> 1,
            RowAlignments -> Baseline, ColumnAlignments -> Center
        ], "\[NoBreak]", ")"}&)
    ] /; IntegerQ@k
]
```

Example of copying and editing of formatted object:

```
Obj[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[image: Obj copying and editing]

Comment: Instead of including `TooltipBox` in the `DisplayFunction`, you could add the option `Tooltip->"Obj"` to the `TemplateBox`.

Comment: @CarlWoll thanks, changed. I had it in `DisplayFunction` because originally tooltip was `RowBox@{"Obj", "[", RowBox@Riffle[Array[Slot, n], ","], "]"}`, but it didn't update after editing formatted expression, so I changed it to a "constant" tooltip.

Comment: This is neat. There are pieces of this I can use on some stuff I'm working on. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Something to start with:

```
Obj /: MakeBoxes[Obj[args__], form : StandardForm] := 
       With[{arr = Partition[{args}, Sqrt[Length[{args}]]]}, 
            With[{boxes = MakeBoxes[MatrixForm[arr], form]}, 
                 InterpretationBox[boxes, Obj[args]]]]
```

I make no attempt to check if the number of arguments is a square number; you can add that check yourself, if you wish.

Comment: This will leak evaluation. e.g. `Hold@Obj[Echo[1], 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: @Kuba what does that mean? Is it bad? EDIT: Removed the accept for now, to make sure I selected the best answer.

Comment: @Kagaratsch, yes, this is why you shouldn't accept answers too quickly. ;) If you're concerned about leaks, then Kuba's approach is certainly better than mine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution:

```
Format[Obj[x__]] := MatrixForm[Partition[{x}, Sqrt[Length[{x}]]]]
```

It seems short and nice, but the solution by J.M. or Kuba is better for the following reason. If we enter an object, then copy-and-paste the output and try `FullForm`, on my objects above we get:

[image]

while the objects of J.M. or Kuba properly give:

[image]

I wonder why `Format` is not implemented a bit more sophisticated? As a naive end-consumer I'd expect it to take the right hand side as a pattern, not directly use it, but go into the box structure and make necessary adjustments automatically to make sure that under any circumstances where the output is copied or transformed to input form, the correct initial input is recovered.