# TagBox + InterpretationBox vs ConvertTo/StandardForm

Tags: formatting, customization, grid-layouts, conversion, boxes

There appears to be a problem with a menu command `Convert To / StandardForm` (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) with respect to `InterpretationBox` which contains `TagBox` (which is how `Column/Grid` and friends are typeset).

Here's an example:

```
obj /: MakeBoxes[obj[arg__], fmt_] := With[
  {appearance = MakeBoxes[Panel[Column[{arg}], "obj"], fmt]}
, InterpretationBox[appearance, obj[arg]]
]

obj[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[image]

```
% // InputForm
```

> obj[1, 2, 3, 4]

So far everything is ok. But select the Input cell containing intial `obj` and use the menu command. This is what happens:

[image]

I find it unexpected because all round trips like

```
ToExpression@MakeBoxes@obj[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

work well.

Question: Is this expected? If yes, what would be a general fix to the typesetting idiom presented above?

Few workarounds are presented in: [Make a custom object look like MatrixForm of a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159337/5478), where this issue came up. But they are not general enough.

The issue was noticed by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159337/make-a-custom-object-look-like-matrixform-of-a-matrix/159340#comment424151_159340) and investigated by [jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159337/make-a-custom-object-look-like-matrixform-of-a-matrix/159340#comment424370_159340) but without any final conclusion.

Answer (score 7):

This report finally found its way to me, and this is not a bug.  I'm sorry support gave you incorrect information.

This has nothing to do with the particular boxes involved, but rather with your use of the typeset generators `Panel` and `Column`.  Most typeset generators, `Graphics` expression, and certain other symbols have "conditional text formatting rules".  Specifically, they check the value of `` BoxForm`UseTextFormattingQ `` when converting to a box from.  This variable defaults to being `True` in input cells and `False` in output, though this can be changed somewhere in the options inspector.  The theory is, if you did Convert To StandardForm on code (say, your `MakeBoxes` rule), you wouldn't necessarily want to go to a form where it can really be easily edited.

So, if you want to create a box structure that always uses box formatting, you can block the variable to `False` like so:

```
obj /: MakeBoxes[obj[arg__], fmt_] := With[
     {appearance = Block[
          {BoxForm`UseTextFormattingQ = False}, 
          MakeBoxes[Panel[Column[{arg}], "obj"], fmt]
     ]}, 
     InterpretationBox[appearance, obj[arg]]
]
```

Workarounds for existing structures would be to use Evaluate in Place rather than Convert To StandardForm (since many of the heads to use this have no evaluation semantics), or change the value of the option `"UseTextFormattingWhenConvertingInput"` to False.

Comment: The solution doesn't seem to work if I modify `Panel[Column[{arg}], "obj"]` to `MatrixForm[{arg}]`?

Comment: Grumble Grumble.  Yes, the `*Forms` are special because of the wrapper stripping behavior.  You can make it work by adding ``Internal`$ConvertForms = {}`` to the `Block` variable list.