# Schrödinger's MatrixForm: feature or bug?

Tags: front-end, formatting, conversion

Recently I noticed a peculiar behavior of `MatrixForm` that I failed to find a way to explain. Consider the following example:

```
a = {{1, 4}, {6, 9}} // MatrixForm;
a
```

My question is, after executing the code above, what is displayed **in the notebook**?

"That's simple! It's `MatrixForm[{{1, 4}, {6, 9}}]`, notice you can't use this directly in evaluation!" Yeah, I thought so, until I tried:

[image]

"…OK, I know how to explain this. There's a number of functions whose output in the notebook is not the same as the one in the kernel, for example, `Format`:

```
Format[int[f_, x_]] := HoldForm@Integrate[f, x]
int[Sin[x], x]
```

[image]

"and `MatrixForm` is just another of them. " Good point, unless `MatrixForm` doesn't behave as follows:

[image]

So the output of `MatrixForm` in the notebook seems to exist as *a combination of multiple states*, it

1. becomes a `List` if you edit and execute it;
2. becomes a `MatrixForm` expression if you edit and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>;
3. remains in a superposition of `List` and `MatrixForm` if you don't edit and just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> alternately.

Another function that behaves like this is `NumberForm`:

```
NumberForm[Pi // N, 10]
```

[image]

There may be more.

Further check shows this behavior has been existing at least since *v3*.

How to understand this behavior? A feature, or a long standing bug?

If it's a feature, is it possible to reproduce this behavior with self-made function?

---

Mr. Wizard thinks this post is a duplicate of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189/121), but that post is really about another issue. Let's look at the example in that post:

```
  mat = {{1, 2}, {3,4}};
  mat // MatrixForm
  Head[%]
```

[image]

I've been aware of this behavior of `MatrixForm` long before I discovered the one mentioned in this question, but I don't find it unexpected at all, because as we can see, in this case the output displays as

```
Out[5] // MatrixForm
```

rather than a single

```
Out[5]
```

which suggests that, the expression stored in `Out[5]` is exactly a `List`, rather than a `MatrixForm` expression. So when we use `%` (which is short for `Out[]`), there's no doubt we'll obtain a `List`.

In a word, that question is about how expression wrapped by `MatrixForm` is 
 stored in the `Out` variable, while mine is about how expression wrapped by `MatrixForm` exists **in the front end**, they're different, though the answer to my question turns out to be related to `$OutputForms`, too.

Comment: Related: [(44189)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189/121), [(132740)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132740/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm sorry, but that post is really about another issue, please check my update. As to [Kuba's post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159959/1871), though Itai thinks my post is essentially a duplicate of that one, the answers to these 2 questions seem to be different at the moment, I think it's better to discuss further for a while and decide if they're duplicate later.

Comment: I reopened and converted my links to "Related" instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159959/tagbox-interpretationbox-vs-convertto-standardform):

1. When typesetting as output, `MatrixForm[_?ArrayQ]` will display matrix-like.
2. In an output cell, Convert To StandardForm will default to box formatting, so you go back and forth between a matrix-like state and an `InputForm`-like state.
3. Once you edit the cell becomes an Input cell, so now `MatrixForm` will use an input-form like state for Convert To StandardForm.

So what's going on with that `TagBox`, and how does `ToExpression@ToBoxes@...` produce a list?  Well, normally the second argument of a `TagBox`, in the absence of more specific rules, is applied as the head of the expression generated from the first argument:

```
MakeExpression[TagBox["a", b], StandardForm] 
(* HoldComplete[b[a]] *)
```

However, an exception is made for heads that are members of `$OutputForms`, where it is ignored:

```
$OutputForms // Unprotect
AppendTo[$OutputForms, b]
MakeExpression[TagBox["a", b], StandardForm]
(* HoldComplete[a] *)
```

This is "wrapper stripping" (the behavior of functions that "affect formatting, but not evaluation") is implemented.  But it would be bad if wrapper stripping occured when you did a Convert To *Form.  Fortunately, that operation doesn't use `MakeExpresion/MakeBoxes`, but rather a dedicated function, which knows not ignore those `TagBox`es.  Here is the call to convert from `StandardForm` to `InputForm`:

```
BoxForm`ConvertForm[TagBox["a", b], StandardForm, InputForm]
(* "b[a]" *)
```

To be perfectly honest, the only reason I can explain this behavior is that I came across the source code for it while fixing a bug, and was able to reproduce the reason for it from the commit message. It is a bit of black magic, but given the relatively small number of questions about it for the last 24 years or so, it is good enough to get the job done.

Comment: Oh, finally here comes a WRI member! So, Convert To StandardForm works differently in Input Cell and Output Cell? Is this behavior controlled by certain option?

Comment: Would you consider posting an answer to [(44189)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189/121)?  It would be illuminating in that context to know how the wrapper stripping is actually performed.

Answer (score 5):

Here are few notes:

Notice the second argument of underying `TagBox[gridbox, Function[e, MatrixForm[e]]`. It guides the interpretation from standard to input form (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). Since `MatrixForm` won't be forgotten, route back to boxes works too.

It is not documented but it seems to work like `ToExpression[gridbox, StandardForm, Function[...]]`. It won't work manually, `ToExpression@ToBoxes@MatrixForm` will return an array. Whether that is expected I don't know but I think this should be more consistent.

Here is another example (bug) showing the difference between Cell/ConvertTo items and composition of ToBoxes/Expression:

[TagBox + InterpretationBox vs ConvertTo/StandardForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159959/5478)

Summing up:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> behavior is governed by `TagBox` (fine but undocumented)
- ability to evaluate typeset `MatrixForm` comes from the fact that `ToExpression` strips it before parsing/evaluation. (arguable)

Comment: @xzczd Yes, fixed. But it does not matter so much as it is only a guess anyway ;)

Comment: "`ToExpression@ToBoxes@MatrixForm` will return an array" I think this example is improper, because the information about `MatrixForm` is removed by `ToBoxes` in this case. (`ToExpression` does ignore `MatrixForm` though: ``TagBox[RowBox[{"(", "\[NoBreak]", GridBox[{{"1", "4"}, {"6", "9"}}], "\[NoBreak]", ")"}],
   Function[BoxForm`e$, MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]] // ToExpression``)

Comment: @xzczd did you mean, it is so but it should not? I agree something is off, maybe it is worth reporting.

Comment: I'm not sure I should say As you've mentioned, the 2nd argument of `TagBox` is undocumented anyway. Perhaps it's time to report to WRI. (I was expecting some WRI member will come and answer this question. )

Comment: Oh… actually I've made a mistake in my second to last comment… I didn't notice `MatrixForm[a]` displays as `a` and thought the `MatrixForm` is ignored by `ToBoxes`…