# How to maintain the form of the formula when using PasteButton?

Tags: front-end, display, button

I want to make a pallet button that keeps the form of the formula intact.

```
PasteButton["\!\(\*RadicalBox[\(\[SelectionPlaceholder]\), \(\\[Placeholder]\)]\)", \
\!\(\*
TagBox[
RadicalBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"],
DisplayForm]\)]
```

[image]

However, the button above is expressed in a different form. How should I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PasteButton["\!\(\*RadicalBox[\(\[SelectionPlaceholder]\), \(\\[Placeholder]\)]\)", 
 RadicalBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"] // DisplayForm]
```

is a possible work-around. To understand why it works, you may want to read the following:

[Schrödinger's MatrixForm: feature or bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175482/1871)

Comment: Thank you. I solved it well.