# Why is the form of the expression not copied in PasteButton?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, standardform, unevaluate, pastebutton

I'm going to make a palette for partial differential and total differential.

```
PasteButton[ Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\),
 \(\[SelectionPlaceholder]\)]\)\[Placeholder]", 16], 
Unevaluated@D[\[SelectionPlaceholder], \[Placeholder]],ImageSize -> {65, 35}]
```

When the button was pressed, the partial differential symbol was well created.

[image]

```
PasteButton[ Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[DifferentialD]\), 
\(\\[SelectionPlaceholder]\)]\)\[Placeholder]", 16],  
Unevaluated@Dt[\[SelectionPlaceholder], \[Placeholder]], ImageSize -> {65, 35}]
```

But this time, if you press the button, it's not an expression. It comes out in the form of Inputform.

[image]

Can I print it out to maintain the form of the equation? I'm going to put the value in the form of the output equation and run it to get the calculated value.

Comment: …Interesting, I didn't know `\[DifferentialD]` can be used in this manner, and this doesn't seem to be documented, how do you notice this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/293806/1871) still works:

```
PasteButton[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[DifferentialD]\), 
\(\\[SelectionPlaceholder]\)]\)\[Placeholder]", 16], 
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[DifferentialD]", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]"], 
    "\[Placeholder]"}] // DisplayForm, ImageSize -> {65, 35}]
```

BTW,the `RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[DifferentialD]", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]"], "\[Placeholder]"}]` is found by

1. Select the expression.
2. Right click, copy as -> cell expression.
3. Paste. (If pasted in notebook, select "No" in popup menu. )

Here's a GIF showing the process:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand for sure.