# How to get output in MatrixForm in this context?

Tags: matrix, front-end, output-formatting, notebooks, formatting

The following code implements matrix arithmetic:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?(Head[#] != Matrix &) + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ  Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_ ?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Exp[Matrix[y] . Log[Matrix[x]]];
Matrix /: Im[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Im[x]];
Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Re[x]];
Matrix /: Arg[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Arg[x]];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[A_?SquareMatrixQ], Matrix[B_?SquareMatrixQ]] := 
 Matrix[KroneckerProduct[A, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
   KroneckerProduct[B, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]]

$Post = FullSimplify[# /. 
f_[args1___?NumericQ, Matrix[mat_], args2___?NumericQ] :> 
 Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1, #, args2] &, mat]]] &;
```

But the output gives expressions like `Matrix[{{0,1/2},{1/2,0}}]`. How can I format output to `MatrixForm`? Adding the line `$PrePrint=MatrixForm` does not help.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159337/1871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$PrePrint = MatrixForm` won't help because `MatrixForm` only has effect on expression whose outermost head is `List`, it doesn't *penetrate* into inner sub-expressions. A simpler example illustrating the issue:

```
MatrixForm[aaa[{{1, 2}, {4, 6}}]]
```

[image]

If you just need to make `Matrix[…]` display as a 2D matrix in traditional math notation,

```
$PrePrint = (# /. Matrix -> MatrixForm)&;
```

or

```
Format@Matrix[a_] := MatrixForm@a
```

will be enough. But as we all know, one of the advantage of *Mathematica* notebook is, output in notebook can be directly edited and used as input, while the definition in `$PrePrint` ruins it. So here's an advanced solution:

```
$PrePrint =.; FormatValues@Matrix = {};
MakeBoxes[Matrix[a_?MatrixQ], StandardForm] ^:= 
 With[{box = 
    GridBox[Map[MakeBoxes, a, {2}], RowSpacings -> 1, ColumnSpacings -> 1, 
     RowAlignments -> Baseline, ColumnAlignments -> Center]},
    TemplateBox[{box}, "Matrix", 
   DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{"[", "\[NoBreak]", #, "\[NoBreak]", "]"} &)]]
```

The advantage of this advanced solution is, it works with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, and the 2D form of `Matrix[…]` is still editable:

[image]

You cannot achieve these with `$PrePrint` or `Format`!

Based on the knowledge obtained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159959/tagbox-interpretationbox-vs-convertto-standardform?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment462173_176005), the following is a more advanced but shorter and more general solution:

```
$PrePrint =.; FormatValues@Matrix = {};
MakeBoxes[Matrix[a_], StandardForm] ^:= 
    Block[{Internal`$ConvertForms = {}}, 
  TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[MatrixForm@a][[1, 1, 3]]}, "Matrix", 
   DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{"[", "\[NoBreak]", #, "\[NoBreak]", "]"} &)]]
```

---

You can further customize the notation for matrix using `StyleBox`:

```
$PrePrint =.; FormatValues@Matrix = {};
Hold[MakeBoxes[Matrix[a_], StandardForm] ^:= 
    Block[{Internal`$ConvertForms = {}}, 
     TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[MatrixForm@a][[1, 1, 3]]}, "Matrix", 
      DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{style@"[", "\[NoBreak]", #, "\[NoBreak]", 
           style@"]"} &)]]] /. 
  style[string_] -> StyleBox[string, FontColor -> Blue] // ReleaseHold
```

Notice I've used the `Hold` & `ReleaseHold` technique to generate the code, because things like `StyleBox[#, FontColor -> Blue] &` simply doesn't work. Even changing `style[string_] ->` to `style[string_] :>` will break the code, because the `Blue` cannot be interpreted. (When using `->`, `Blue` will evaluate to `RGBColor[0, 0, 1]`. )

Comment: Is there a way to make the brackets in another color (say, red)?

Comment: @Anixx Of course, see my edit.

Comment: This is working very well! I am thinking now, what other matrix functions I can add to this code.