# How to build a TemplateBox with dynamic length GridBox?

Tags: boxes, custom-notation

I have created the following TemplateBox Rule.

```
MakeBoxes[ActuarialSurvivalProbability[x_,t_],StandardForm]:=TemplateBox[{
        MakeBoxes[#,StandardForm]&/@x,
        MakeBoxes[t,StandardForm]
    },
    "ActuarialSurvivalProbability",
    DisplayFunction:>(RowBox[{
        SubscriptBox[
            "",
            TagBox[GridBox[{{#2}},GridBoxDividers->{}],"Grid"]
        ],
        SubscriptBox[
            "p",
            RowBox[{
                "",
                TagBox[GridBox[{#1},GridBoxDividers->{
                    "ColumnsIndexed"->{},
                    "RowsIndexed"->{1->Thickness[1]}
                }],"Grid"]
            }]
        ]
    }]&),
    Tooltip->"probability that atleast one of live(s) aged "<>ToString[x]<>" survives for "<>ToString[t]<>" year(s)"
]
```

Then I evaluate the following.

```
ActuarialSurvivalProbability[{x, y, z}, t]
```

I expect an answer like that generated from the following command:

```
RawBoxes@TemplateBox[{
        MakeBoxes[#,StandardForm]&/@{"x","y","z"},
        MakeBoxes[t,StandardForm]
    },
    "ActuarialSurvivalProbability",
    DisplayFunction:>(RowBox[{
        SubscriptBox[
            "",
            TagBox[GridBox[{{#2}},GridBoxDividers->{}],"Grid"]
        ],
        SubscriptBox[
            "p",
            RowBox[{
                "",
                TagBox[GridBox[{{"x","y","z"}},GridBoxDividers->{
                    "ColumnsIndexed"->{},
                    "RowsIndexed"->{1->Thickness[1]}
                }],"Grid"]
            }]
        ]
    }]&),
    Tooltip->"probability that atleast one of live(s) aged "<>ToString[{"x","y","z"}]<>" survives for "<>ToString[t]<>" year(s)"
]
```

But instead the dynamic length of input fed to `GridBox` in `DisplayFunction` in `{#1}` as `{"x","y","z"}` is not formatting correctly.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to jkuczm for an idea: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159407/5478:

```
MakeBoxes[ActuarialSurvivalProbability[x_, t_], StandardForm] := 
 With[{row = Table[Slot[i], {i, 2, Length[x] + 1}]} (*Key point,
  row of slots generated*), 
  TemplateBox[
   Prepend[MakeBoxes /@ Unevaluated@x, 
    MakeBoxes[t]] , 
   "ActuarialSurvivalProbability",
   InterpretationFunction -> (RowBox[{"ActuarialSurvivalProbability", 
        "[", RowBox[{RowBox[{"{", RowBox[Riffle[{##2}, ","]], "}"}], 
          ",", #}], "]"}] &), 
   DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{SubscriptBox["", 
         TagBox[GridBox[{{#}}, GridBoxDividers -> {}], "Grid"]], 
        SubscriptBox["p", 
         RowBox[{"", 
           TagBox[GridBox[{row}, 
             GridBoxDividers -> {"ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
               "RowsIndexed" -> {1 -> Thickness[1]}}], "Grid"]}]]}] &),

   Tooltip -> 
    "probability that atleast one of live(s) aged " <> ToString[x] <> 
     " survives for " <> ToString[t] <> " year(s)"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! you can also add a `lastSlot` variable like `lastSlot=Slot[Length@x+1]` inside `With` to fix the variable `t` in the formatting. But there is one problem if you copy this notation and evaluate it, it gives `ActuarialSurvivalProbability[x, y, z, t]` instead of the original `ActuarialSurvivalProbability[{x, y, z}, t]`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user13892 right, take a look now

Comment: Thanks you it works now.

Comment: Thank you @Kuba for the excellent answer. I would like to ask why the `DisplayFunction` is using `RuleDelayed` rather than just a `Rule` is it necessary? because i see the documentation using it as well.

Comment: @user13892 I am not 100% but I don't think it is necessary because Function or whatever you put there should not evaluate unless arguments are applied anyway. Otoh it is usually to follow docs because the fact that it does not matter does not imply it is implemented for Rule too :)

Comment: Thank you one last thing. Is it possible to make the `DisplayFunction` conditional on the values of the input parameter say `t`. So if `t=1`. I want it to display say without presubscript.

Comment: Or i will have to make a lot of separate definitions otherwise.

Comment: @user13892 do you need contents to be editable? If not you can use InterpretationBox and keep original input and switch layout based on t or whatever.

Comment: i would want the notation to be able to be copied across various formula manually and remain connected to the corresponding `ActuarialSurvivalProbability[...]` definition.

Comment: @user13892 I think that deserves a separate question. If you post it please add special forms you want to care about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TemplateSlotSequence` for variable length [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) arguments:

```
MakeBoxes[ActuarialSurvivalProbability[x_, t_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[
    Prepend[MakeBoxes[t]] @ BoxForm`ListMakeBoxes[x, StandardForm],
    "ActuarialSurvivalProbability",
    InterpretationFunction -> (
        RowBox[{
            "ActuarialSurvivalProbability", 
            "[", 
            RowBox[{
                RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{TemplateSlotSequence[2, ","]}], "}"}],
                ",",
                #1
            }],
            "]"
        }]&
    ),
    DisplayFunction -> (
        RowBox[{
            SubscriptBox["", #1],
            SubscriptBox[
                "p",
                RowBox[{
                    "",
                    GridBox[
                        {{TemplateSlotSequence[2]}},
                        GridBoxDividers->{"RowsIndexed"->{1->Thickness[1]}}
                    ]
                }]
            ]
        }]&
    ),
    Tooltip->"probability that at least one of live(s) aged "<>ToString[x]<>
        " survives for "<>ToString[t]<>" year(s)"
]
```

Then:

```
ActuarialSurvivalProbability[{x, y, z}, t]
```

> [image]

The advantage of using a `TemplateSlotSequence` solution is that the `DisplayFunction`/`InterpretationFunction` can be defined in a stylesheet.

**A brief comment on `TemplateSlotSequence`**

I think since the pure functions used in `DisplayFunction` and `InterpretationFunction` do not evaluate in the Wolfram Language kernel, `TemplateSlotSequence` was introduced as a way to enhance the creation of box structures. When the front end constructs the box expression using the `DisplayFunction`/`InterpretationFunction`, `TemplateSlotSequence` objects are interpreted as:

```
TemplateSlotSequence[1] -> Sequence[#1, #2, ...]
TemplateSlotSequence[2, ","] -> Sequence[#2, ",", #3, ",", ...]
TemplateSlotSequence[{3, 5}, " "] -> Sequence[#3, " ", #4, " ", #5]
```

Note that the above is not documented, and as with all undocumented functionality, it is subject to change.

Comment: Any explanation why does it work? At the end those are *Functions not Templates.

Comment: @Kuba Both answers are nice and  works. (I came to similar solutions for variable index tensor notation.)  However, suppose I want to add extra argument after I copied the Displayed form structure  into a new notebook cell. Neither of the proposed solutions nor my solution allows to to this. Is it possible to extend code which would allow extra editing in the copied Display structure?

Comment: @user18792 you can add `Editable -> True` to the `TemplateBox`.

Comment: @user18792 As far as I know, it is not possible to increase the number of template arguments through normal editing. If you use Show Expression, then of course it is possible to change the number of template arguments.

Comment: @Kuba It does not add extra argument to the argument list. It multiplies one of arguments by a new symbol.

Comment: Ok. If somebody will find a solution it will be extremely  handy. Just imagine: you copy a nice tensor with arguments indicated by scripts, then edit by adding new argument and send for evaluation in a nice form without a need to go back/forward with a long representation form. Of course, editing without change a number of arguments works as expected.