# Making function $S$ such that inputs as an list $\{1,3,2,4, \}$ and produces $s_{1234}$

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, sorting, numeric-array

I want to make $S[\{,\cdots, \}]$ as follows

First input of $S$ is given list $\{1,2,3,\cdots, n\}$ and it produces $s_{123\cdots n}$

Further, if the ordering of the list is given differently, still gives increasing order. i.e.,

$S[{1,3,2}] = s_{123}$

$S[{1,2,4,3}] = s_{1234}$

and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html), [`Interpretation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpretation.html), and [`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html):

```
Attributes[S] = {Orderless};

Format[e : S[args___]] := Interpretation[Subscript[s, Row@{args}], e]

S[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

[image: (* S[1, 2, 3, 4] *)]

```
S[1, 2, 4, 3] // InputForm
(* S[1, 2, 4, 3] *)
```

The use of `Interpretation` ensures that you can still use the expression when copy-pasting it (see the last example). The `Orderless` attribute does the sorting automatically, and also makes it so that different orderings are considered equivalent:

```
S[1, 2, 4, 3] == S[4, 3, 2, 1]
(* True *)
```

If you want some spacing between the different subscripts, you can use [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html):

```
Format[e : S[args___]] := Interpretation[Indexed[s, {args}], e]

S[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

[image]

If you really need `S[{...}]` instead of simply `S[...]`, you can't use `Orderless`. You'll have to manually sort the arguments, e.g. like this:

```
S[args_] /; ! OrderedQ@args := S[Sort@args]

Format[e : S[args_]] := Interpretation[Subscript[s, Row@args], e]

S[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

[image: (* S[1, 2, 3, 4] *)]

The first line automatically sorts the arguments of `S` if they are not already sorted (using [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`) and [`OrderedQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderedQ.html))

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a pure function, like this:

```
ClearAll[S]
S = Subscript[s, Row[{##} // Flatten // Sort, " "]] &;

S[{1, 2, 3, 4}]

S[1, 3, 2]
```

[image]

Notice the use of `##` in the above to refer to the function arguments.
If you don't like so much space between the subscripts, use

```
ClearAll[S]
S = Subscript[s, Row[{##} // Flatten // Sort]] &;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an input to be a `List` then e.g.:

```
S[list_] := Subscript[S, StringDelete[ToString[Sort[list]], {",", " ","{", "}"}]]
```

If a `Sequence` then e.g.:

```
R[seq__] := Subscript[R, StringDelete[ToString[{seq}], {",", " ", "{", "}"}]]
```

I'm sure there are other (better) ways, but these might need to be tailored to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First, look at [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187654/how-to-build-a-templatebox-with-dynamic-length-gridbox[templatebox-with-dynamic-length-gridbox][1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187654/how-to-build-a-templatebox-with-dynamic-length-gridbox%5Btemplatebox-with-dynamic-length-gridbox%5D%5B1%5D) since similar questions already have answers

My solution (adopted from more general context) is below. With little more adaptation the output even can be copied, edited and reused, assuming that you do not change number of indices (this seems is limitation of current Mathematica two dimensional input template possibilities).

```
MakeBoxes[mvDownUp[{indown___Integer}, {inup___Integer}], 
   sf : StandardForm] := With[{
    argsa = Riffle[Flatten[Rest /@ Sort[
         Transpose[{{indown, inup}, 
           Join[Table[
             AdjustmentBox[Slot[i], BoxBaselineShift -> 1], {i, 
              Length[{indown}]}], 
            Table[AdjustmentBox[Slot[i], BoxBaselineShift -> -1], {i, 
              Length[{indown}] + 1, Length[{indown, inup}]}]]}]
         ]], ","]
    },
   With[{
     pfd =
      Function[
       StyleBox[RowBox[argsa], FontSize -> Small, 
        FontTracking -> "Condensed", AutoSpacing -> False]],
     pfi = 
      ReleaseHold[
        RowBox[{"mvDownUp", "@@", 
          MakeExpression[{Take[{##}, Length[{indown}]], 
            Take[{##}, {Length[{indown}] + 1, 
              Length[{indown, inup}]}]}, sf]}]] &
     },
    TemplateBox[
     Flatten[{MakeBoxes[#, sf] & /@ {indown}, 
       MakeBoxes[#, sf] & /@ {inup}}], "mvDownUp", 
     DisplayFunction :> pfd, InterpretationFunction :> pfi, 
     SyntaxForm -> "fish", 
     Tooltip -> ToString[mvDownUp[{indown}, {inup}]]]
    ]
   ];

With[{baseSymbolN = "S", bs = Symbol["S"]},
 MakeBoxes[bs[in_mvDownUp], sf : StandardForm] := 
  With[{sty = (FontColor -> Black), inEx = MakeBoxes[in, sf]},
   With[{
     pfd = 
      Function[
       StyleBox[RowBox[{StyleBox[baseSymbolN, sty], #1}], 
        AutoSpacing -> False, FontTracking -> "Condensed"]], 
     pfi = Function[RowBox[{baseSymbolN, "[", #1, ",", #2, "]"}]]}, 
    TemplateBox[{inEx}, baseSymbolN, DisplayFunction :> pfd, 
     InterpretationFunction :> pfi, SyntaxForm -> "fish"]]]]

S[x_List] := S[mvDownUp[Sort[x], {}]] /; ! OrderedQ[x]

S[x_List] := S[mvDownUp[x], {}]

S[{3, 1, 2, 7}]
```