# Pretty print of Association with Format, how to?

Tags: formatting, associations

I have some assocations, containing a lot of data, lets say something like

```
<|"x"->{... big list ...},....|>
```

I would like to print these associations in a convenient and concise form, let's say:

```
x:[xMinValue,xMaxValue] (where xMinValue=Min[{..Big List...}]...)
```

For this purpose my idea was to use the `Format` command. Reading the official mma doc I have this example:

```
Format[f[x_?ListQ]] := "f[x], x:[" <> ToString[Min[x]] <> ", " <> ToString[Max[x]] <> "]"
```

For example:

```
f[Range[20]]]
```

> f[x], x:[1, 20]

However, and **this is my problem**, I have no success with `Association`:

```
Format[<|"x"->x_?ListQ|>] := "x:[" <> ToString[Min[x]] <> ", " <> ToString[Max[x]] <> "]"
```

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Association in
>   MakeBoxes[Association[x_?ListQ],FormatType_] is Protected.
>
> SetDelayed::write: Tag Association in Association[x_?ListQ] is
>   Protected.

**My question:** how to define custom and pretty print of `Association`?

Comment: First, `Association` have the propertiy `Protected`, so you have to `Unprotect` them first. Second, `Association`s are atomic. Hence, pattern matching within `Association`s does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a closely related answer: [149668](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149668/5478)

`MakeBoxes` does not need to assign to `Association` in exchange for an overhead which usually is not a problem (see [39675](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39675/121))

Also, be extremely careful during pattern matching / calculations for formatting/typesetting. Your `_?ListQ` will evaluate content to confirm pattern even if the expression is somewhere inside `Hold` or something. Try `Hold@<|"x" -> (Print[1]; {1, 2, 3})|>`

Summing up, here's something to work with:

```
With[
  { safeNumListQ = Function[elem, NumericQ[Unevaluated[elem]], HoldAllComplete]
  }
, MakeBoxes[
    Association["x" -> x : {__?safeNumListQ}], fmt_
  ] := StringTemplate["\"x:[``, ``]\""] @@ MinMax[x]
]
```

In general you need to care about evaluation on `MinMax` stage too but here we already confirmed it is a numerical list and `MinMax` won't leak anything.

```
<|"x" -> {1, 2, 3}|>
Hold@<|"x" -> {1, 2, 3, Print[1]}|>
Hold@<|"x" -> {1, 2, 3}|>
Hold@<|"x" -> (Print[1]; {1, 2, 3})|>
```

[image]

Further reading:

- [Prevent graphics render inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32296/5478)
- [Make a custom object look like MatrixForm of a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159337/5478)
- [Understanding evaluation and typesetting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114305/5478)

Comment: Thanks for your expertise I will carefully read your post and improve my code.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a way to do it. Use it without any guarantees from my side.

```
Unprotect[Association];
format[x_List] := "<< Very long list that we do not want to see, honestly. >>";
format[x_] := x;
Association /: Format[a_Association] := 
 Row[{"\[LeftAssociation]", 
   Sequence @@ 
    Riffle[Rule @@@ Transpose[{Keys[a], format /@ Values[a]}], ", "], 
   "\[RightAssociation]"}]
Protect[Association];
```

Here some example to see the effect:

```
Association["Bli" -> 1, "Bla" -> Association["Blabla" -> {2, 3}], "Blubb" -> {4, 5}]
```

Comment: Great! That was the kind of solution I was looking for. Many thanks. I will just wait a little bit to see if another solution is proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @HenrikSchumacher answer, here is my answer, that filters the Association type I want to print in a special way.

First I define this test, used to check association type:

```
MyAssocationQ[assoc_] := MatchQ[assoc, <|"x" -> _?ListQ|>]
```

For instance:

```
MyAssocationQ[<|"x" -> {-5, 2, 9}|>]
```

returns

> True

however

```
MyAssocationQ[2017]
MyAssocationQ[<|"x" -> {-5, 2, 9},"y"->1|>]
```

return

> False
>
> False

Then, following Henrik approach, we have to `Unprotect` the `Assocation` symbol, and define

```
Unprotect[Association];

Association /: Format[assoc_Association /; MyAssocationQ[assoc]] := 
  "x:[" <> ToString[Min[assoc["x"]]] <> ", " <> 
  ToString[Max[assoc["x"]]] <> "]";

Protect[Association];
```

Then I get the expected behavior:

```
In[]= <|"x" -> {-5, 2, 9}|>
```

> Out[]= x:[-5, 9]

and

```
In[]= <|"x" -> {-5, 2, 9}, "y" -> 5|>
```

> Out[]= <|"x" -> {-5, 2, 9}, "y" -> 5|>

is unaffected and is the usual behavior.