# Possible to create an input cell containing Graphics/Graphics3D without Hold?

Tags: front-end

I am trying to implement a function that takes a `Graphics` instruction as its argument and then duplicated it in a new `InputCell`. I'm aware about the render of `Graphics` is typesetting process [as explained here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32296/prevent-graphics-from-rendering-inside-a-held-expression). And use the techniques in that post I came up with the following

```
Unprotect@Hold;
mk : MakeBoxes[Blank[Hold], _] /; ! TrueQ[$hldGfx] ^:= 
  Block[{$hldGfx = True, Graphics, Graphics3D}, mk];
Protect@Hold;

SetAttributes[printGraphics, HoldFirst];
printGraphics[graphics_] :=
 CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{
      ToBoxes[Hold[graphics]]
      }]], "Input"]]
```

Running`printGraphics@Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}]` will create a cell with `Hold[Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}]]`.

My question is that if it's possible to create a cell without `Hold`.

If you are interested in the reason I need this, here is the functionality I'm working on: see Section **Minimal example** in [here (Github: PrettyColorize)](https://github.com/yuluyan/PrettyColorize). `Plot`, `Plot3D` or other plotting function can be easily printed while `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` are a little tricky and I'm not sure how to get over.

Comment: Use `Unevaluated` instead of `Hold` when calling `ToBoxes`. That should be all you need.

Comment: Also that `MakeBoxes` is probably a bit more than you want if you can control the `Print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to avoid the `MakeBoxes` call and the `Hold` at the same time:

```
SetAttributes[printGraphics, HoldFirst];
printGraphics[graphics_Graphics] :=
 Block[{myGraphics, gb},
  gb =
   Replace[Hold[graphics], 
    Hold[Graphics[a___]] :>
     (ToBoxes[Unevaluated@myGraphics[a]] /. "myGraphics" -> "Graphics")
    ];
  CellPrint[
   Cell[BoxData[gb], "Input"]
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: Cool! I do need to look more into these Hold/Unevaluated/Inactive/... functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [`DisableFormatting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisableFormatting):

```
printGraphics[graphics_] := CellPrint @ Cell[
    BoxData @ MakeBoxes[DisableFormatting[graphics]][[1, 1, 1]],
    "Input"
]
```

For example:

```
printGraphics[Graphics[{Circle[]}]]
```

> Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}]

Comment: Thanks! Good to know this `DisableFormatting` function.