# How to see abstract syntax tree of Wolfram Language expression

Tags: syntax, core-language

I mean, suppose I have this expression:

2 + 2

I want to get something like this:

Plus[2, 2]

as an output. I've tried FullForm, but this just evaluates 2+2 and returns 4. Is this even possible?

Comment: Try `2+2//Hold//FullForm`

Comment: Have a look at `HoldForm`

Comment: You can try prepending a Hold.  `Hold[2+2] // FullForm`.  You might also like `TreeForm` for this purpose.

Comment: Generally, what you are seeking is to prevent kernel evaluation. `Hold` and its ilk (`Defer`, `Unevaluated`, `Inactive`, etc.) are the mechanisms for this, depending on precisely what you want. Look at [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EvaluationControl.html) for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tree = Function[x, Defer @ FullForm @ x, HoldAll];
```

Now:

```
2 + 2 // tree
```

> ```
> Plus[2, 2]
> ```

I used [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) to allow the output to be evaluated.  If you do not prefer this replace it with [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html).

For some explanation of the mechanics of this code see:  [Why doesn't "Defer" work with "TableForm"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/why-doesnt-defer-work-with-tableform/16675#16675)

See also [my standard methods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121) for analyzing parsing.