# Equation values into list

Tags: syntax

Suppose I have a function say $f=x^2$. What I would like is a list (or even better, a list with a grid) which resembles `{{1,1},{2,4},{3,9}, ...}`. Ideally one should be able to specify the starting point, end point and step interval between values.

This seem like such a simple idea I don't know why I am struggling with it...

Comment: Please have a look at `Table`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of table; and have managed to do almost what I desire, but I only obtain one set of values.

I.e: {1,4,9,...} as opposed to {{1,1},{2,4},{3,9}}

Comment: @Ronan `Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 5}]` ?

Comment: ... Ok, yes I am that oblivious. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *Mathematica*'s [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) function, you can do it this way:

```
f[x_] := x^2

xList = Range[10]

(* ==> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)

values = Map[f, xList]

(* ==> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100} *)

grid = Transpose[{xList, values}]

(*
==> {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}, {7, 
  49}, {8, 64}, {9, 81}, {10, 100}}
*)
```

Comment: Perfect! I had not even thought of mapping onto the xaxis. This is exactly what I wanted.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Many functions, such as the one you've defined

```
f[x_]:=x^2
```

are automatically listable. This means that you can get a list of the values directly using

```
f[Range[10]]
```

to get the `f` applied to the first 10 integer values. To get the form you desire, a listing of `{x_value, f[x_value]}` pairs can be constructed straightforwardly as

```
Transpose[{Range[10], f[Range[10]]}]
```

or somewhat more concisely as:

```
{#, f[#]} & /@ Range[10]
```

Answer (score 2):

With `f` already defined:

```
f = #^2 &;
```

The most direct way is perhaps [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[{#, f@#} &, 3]
```

Of course [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) may be used as well, as [R.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) proposed:

```
Table[{i, f@i}, {i, 3}]
```

Better for performance is the method using [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html), but with the given function there is an additional optimization that may be made.  The function `Power`, of which `f` is composed, is a Listable function and has optimizations for application to vectors and arrays.  We could therefore write:

```
{#, f@#}\[Transpose] & @ Range@3
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}
> ```

Note that there is no `Map` here; that is handled by `Power` itself.  See: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121) for some additional examples.

For formatting "a list with a grid" you should look at [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html), [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TableForm.html), and [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html).  Be aware that these are formatting wrappers<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16675/121),[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11066/121)</sup> that affect output generation but remain part of the expression.

For the sake of formatting alone you may not even need `Transpose`:

```
TableForm[{#, f@#} &@Range@3]

TableForm[{{#, f@#} &@Range@3}]  (* note the extra set of {} *)
```

[image]

[image]

---

p.s. Another user posted, then deleted, an answer using `MapIndexed`, but the form didn't quite make sense.  While is it not needed here I suspect that something like this was the intent:

```
MapIndexed[{First @ #2, #} &, Array[f, 3]]
```

Comment: You may want to add another way `{x,x^2}/.{x->#}&/@Range@3`.

Comment: @Kuba That doesn't use `f` however.  Shorter would be merely `{#, #^2}& ~Array~ 3` if we allow such changes.

Comment: So put there f :) `f = #^2 &; {x, f[x]} /. {x -> #} & /@ Range@3` My point was to use `ReplaceAll` in that way it create an array. I know it is not useful but another method just for fun since it is not closed :)

Comment: How about `MapIndexed[{Tr@#2, #} &, Array[f, 3]]`?

Comment: @chyanog That's clever! :-)  I usually use e.g. `#2[[1]]` which looks a bit better and is equally terse (but longer to write) with the special characters in a Notebook.  In `MapIndexed` I usually try to preserve extensibility to deeper levels and `Tr` would change behavior there whereas `First` would not.