# FullForm applied to functions

Tags: functions

I would have expected

```
FullForm[Cases[{a^2, a^3}, a_^1]]
```

to produce `Cases[List[Power[a, 2], Power[a ,3]], Pattern[a, Blank[]]]`

Instead it produces only `List[Power[a, 2], Power[a ,3]]`

In contrast,

```
FullForm[Log[10, x + y]]
```

produces a complete representation, `Times[Power[Log[10],-1], Log[Plus[x, y]]]

I would appreciate a work-around for the first example, or at least an explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: `FullForm` shows the **result** of the calculation.  It's not `HoldAll`.

Comment: **To the close-voters**: nowhere in the documentation of `FullForm` (that I can see) is a method given to show the unevaluated verbose form of an expression.  I therefore contend that it is not "easily found in the documentation."

Comment: @Yves "I would appreciate a work-around for the first example ..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) is a formatting wrapper<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16675/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11066/121)[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61211/121)</sup>.  It does not change the way that the expression it contains evaluates but rather the way it is displayed by the Front End.  You can combine it with [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html), which is another formatting wrapper that specifically holds its argument, to show the unevaluated full form of an expression:

```
Cases[{a^2, a^3}, a_^1] // FullForm // HoldForm
```

> ```
> Cases[List[Power[a, 2], Power[a, 3]], Power[Pattern[a, Blank[]], 1]]
> ```

Note that as formatting wrappers neither of these is explicitly shown in the output, though they both affect it, and they both remain as part of the expression which can be seen with yet another wrapper, [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html):

```
% // InputForm
```

> ```
> HoldForm[FullForm[Cases[{a^2, a^3}, (a_)^1]]]
> ```

(See [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html) if you are unfamiliar with `%` notation.)

---

Somewhat related:

- [Using a list of tuples in a pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3143/121)
- [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121)

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned in the comment: `FullForm` is a function that evaluates in the standard way because it has no attribute saying otherwise. One consequence is that before `FullForm` acts on your input, it evaluates it, which leave only the result of cases.

None of this helps you to get your answer anyway. One easy way is to use `Unevaluated` on arguments to get what you like

```
FullForm[Unevaluated[Cases[{a^2,a^3},a_^1]]]
(* Unevaluated[Cases[List[Power[a,2],Power[a,3]],Power[Pattern[a,Blank[]],1]]] *)
```

This works, but you will have the `Unevaluated` in your output. Another way is to temporarily give `FullForm` an attribute to hold its argument. This can be achieved with `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{FullForm},
  SetAttributes[FullForm,{HoldFirst}];
  Print[FullForm[Cases[{a^2,a^3},a_^1]]]
]

(* Cases[List[Power[a,2],Power[a,3]],Power[Pattern[a,Blank[]],1]] *)
```

You may ask why I *print* the output. The problem is that as soon as we leave the block, *Mathematica* restores the normal behavior of `FullForm` which leads to an evaluation like you have seen it. Another way of getting the ouput that *looks* like it doesn't evaluate anymore is to replace the last line in the block with

```
HoldForm[#] &[FullForm[Cases[{a^2, a^3}, a_^1]]]
```

This should give you a start how to handle those cases in future. I strongly recommend that you read the [Tutorial on Non-Standard Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html) and the references therein.