# 'MatrixForm' problem

Tags: matrix

I prefer to use 'MatrixForm' because the form looks better in matrix manipulation. But my current problem is that after the use of 'MatrixForm', subsequent matrix calculations like 'Det' or 'Inverse' do not work well. I guess that they're very easy to solve, but I don't know how (because I'm just starting). Please let me know the solution. Thanks !

Comment: This question has been answered in list item number six in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/731) answer.

Comment: Please see the link inserted at the top of your question.  Also recommended reading: [(16664)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16664/121), [(70022)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70022/121)