# How to convert input expression to FullForm String

Tags: string-manipulation, output, conversion, hold

Is there a way to convert an input expression to FullForm String?

Here is my attempt, which is almost there.

```
SetAttributes[fullFormString, HoldAll];
fullFormString[expr_] := ToString[FullForm[Unevaluated[expr]], OutputForm]
```

But `Unevaluated` appears in the string, which I don't want.

```
fullFormString[Integrate[α^2, {α, -3, 3}]]
```

> `"Unevaluated[Integrate[Power[\\[Alpha], 2], List[\\[Alpha], -3, 3]]]"`

The escaped `\` is correct. I just need the canonical way to make a `FullForm` string without the `Unevaluated`.

Comment: I suppose I could postprocess the output using `StringReplace`, but is there a better way?

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(70022)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70022/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just put [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated) in the wrong spot:

```
SetAttributes[fullFormString, HoldAll];
fullFormString[expr_] := ToString[Unevaluated @ FullForm[expr]]
```

For your example:

```
fullFormString[Integrate[\[Alpha]^2, {\[Alpha], -3, 3}]]
```

> "Integrate[Power[\[Alpha], 2], List[\[Alpha], -3, 3]]"

Comment: Oh that's very good.  Do you know why `Unevaluated` is not stripped in `FullForm`?  I thought `Unevaluated` simply sets the attributes of the outer function, rather than actually being processed by it.  Also, would you have any recommendations about using your method vs @HenrikSchumacker's method (involving `HoldForm`)?

Comment: `FullForm` doesn't have `DownValues`, so the `Unevaluated` never gets stripped. I think `Unevaluated` is slightly better as it avoids evaluating anything, while the `HoldForm` approach evaluates the `HoldForm` object, which is inert because of it's `Hold` attributes, and the `HoldForm` approach relies on correct formatting of `HoldForm` when converting to `OutputForm`. For example, `HoldForm` doesn't disappear when converting to `InputForm`.

Comment: Ah I see; that makes sense.  I also notice `FullForm` doesn't disappear when converting to `InputForm` either.  It's stripped only when converting to `OutputForm`.  I wish I understood this part of the evaluation process better.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this way?

```
SetAttributes[fullFormString, HoldAll];
fullFormString[expr_] := ToString[HoldForm[FullForm[expr]], OutputForm]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe this way?

```
SetAttributes[fullFormString, HoldAll];
fullFormString[expr_] := 
  StringReplace[
    ToString[FullForm[Unevaluated[expr]], OutputForm], 
    "Unevaluated[" ~~ Longest[u__] ~~ "]" -> u]

fullFormString[Integrate[α^2, {α, -3, 3}]]
```

> `"Integrate[Power[\\[Alpha], 2], List[\\[Alpha], -3, 3]]"`

Comment: This works, but it's very similar to my "postprocessing" method mentioned in my comments.  @Henrik's method seems to be working for all my cases.  Is there really no built-in function to achieve my task?

Comment: @QuantumDot. Not that I know of.